# Zu Heilig Abend, oder Zum heiligen Abend

Tags: grammar, preposition

Do you say:

> zu Heilig Abend

or

> zum heiligen Abend

or

> zum Heiligen Abend

or something else? The usage shoud be like the example

> Zu Heilig Abend gingen wir in die Kirche.

I'm not sure, about the usage of *zum* in combination with the proper name.

Comment: Regardless of any prepositions it's `Heiligabend` or `Heiliger Abend`, but not `Heilig Abend`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most common [usage](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Heiligabend):

> Am/An Heiligabend gingen wir in die Kirche.

*Heiligabend* with *zu* is [not commonly used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+Heiligabend%2Czu+Heiligabend%2C+am+Heiligabend&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20Heiligabend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czu%20Heiligabend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20Heiligabend%3B%2Cc0):

> Zu Heiligabend gibt es bei uns immer Fisch.
>   An Heiligabend gibt es bei uns immer Fisch.
>   Am Heiligabend gab es dieses Jahr bei uns Fischstäbchen.

*An* / *Zu* in this context is used to make a general statement true for all instances of Heiligabend or for future instances of Heiligabend. The statement above would mean that you have fish for christmas eve every time.

*Am* would mean a specific instance of a Heiligabend, in the above example the next christmas eve is bound to include fish sticks for supper/dinner.

Colloquially, you could even omit the preposition and leave it up for interpretation/assumption, what you want to express:

> Heiligabend gibt es bei uns Fisch.

---

Please verify whether *an* / *am* can be used with your intended date/event, as commentors have pointed out, *Ostern* is not common with *an* in [some regions](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ostern).

Comment: *An Ostern steigt die Selbstmordrate von Hasen dramatisch an* - Wieso geht *an* in dem Zusammenhang nicht? [Der Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ostern) behauptet zwar das wäre schweizerisch, aber ich finde es hört sich nicht verkehrt an. @falk

Comment: wobei ich dachte, *zu* und *an* sind alte Wendungen und man sagt modern nur noch *am* für alles

Comment: Vermutlich wirklich regional, ich höre oft noch *zu Ostern* oder *an Heiligabend* und nutze es auch selbst so.

Comment: ja stimmt, Ostern geht eigentlich nur mit *zu* hier, *an* klingt wie aus dem Märchenbuch

Comment: Das sehe ich ganz anders. "Was macht Ihr an Ostern?" wäre meine Formulierung der Wahl (Südhessen). "Zu Ostern" passt imo besser bei "Was hast Du zu Ostern bekommen?".

Comment: Ich hab es extra neutral formuliert in der Antwort. Kann ich die so stehen lassen oder seht ihr dort editier-Bedarf?

Comment: es ist hier - denke ich - *-abend*-gesteuert. Merkt man, wenn man's noch mit *Weihnachten* vegleicht

Comment: Der Unterschied zwischen `an` und `am` liegt nicht in der Generalität, sondern darin, ob man `Heilig Abend` als Namen mit undeklinierbarem Adjektivbestandteil ansieht oder nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Beides.

> Zu Heilig Abend erwarten wir Gäste.
>
> Der Adventskalender bleibt bis zum Heiligen Abend stehen.

Comment: The spelling is important: If the adjective is not inflected, the phrase is taken as a compound noun and needs to be spelled as such (i.e. "Zu Heiligabend").

Answer (score 1):

You can say the two first answers. `Heilig Abend` is a name for the day derived from the group `der heilige Abend`. Some people still see the `heilig` as a true adjektive attribute, other see it as a part of the fixed name.

Fixed name:

> Zu Heilig Abend gingen wir in die Kirche.

Adjektive attribute:

> Zum heiligen Abend gingen wir in die Kirche.

PS: Be aware, that the preposition `zu/zum` is used if referring to the special occasion of `heilig Abend` (Family coming together, some rituals, presents, …). If you just want to refer to the day, you should use `an/am`, as is propably more commonly done.

Answer (score 0):

We use "An Heiligabend" or "Am heiligen Abend" (second is less common here, but might be local)

This may differ in many regions where german is spoken, but this is the grammatically correct version.

e.g. "An Heiligabend gingen wir in die Kirche."

Answer (score 0):

In Austria you say neither »zu« nor »zum«. You say »am«. You also don't use »Heiligabend« in Austria. We use »Heiliger Abend«. The adjective »Heiliger« is written with an uppercase H since »Heiliger Abend« is a proper name.

This is the usage in Austria:

> **Am Heiligen Abend** wird der Christbaum aufgeputzt.
>   Tante Erika wird uns **am Heiligen Abend** besuchen.
>   Bei Familie Fuchs gibt es **am Heiligen Abend** immer einen Karpfen, bei uns aber eine Gans.

---

**Additional Information**

The name of the two holidays after christmas eve are different in Germany, Austria and Switzerland:

**25th of December**
Germany: *Erster Weihnachtstag*
Austria: *Christtag*
Switzerland: *Weihnachten*

**26th of December**
Germany: *Zweiter Weihnachtstag*
Austria: *Stefanitag* (spoken with a long and stressed a: stefAAnitag)
Switzerland: *Stephanstag*